# Operate with Apache Cassandra list

Tags: cassandra

I have next table structure in Cassandra:

```
CREATE TABLE statistics (
  clientId VARCHAR,
  hits LIST<text>,
  PRIMARY KEY (clientId)
);

INSERT INTO statistics(clientId, hits) VALUES ('clientId', [{'referer': 'http://example.com/asd', 'type': 'PAGE', 'page': '{"title": "Page title"}'}, {'referer': 'http://example.com/dsa', 'type': 'EVENT', 'event': '{"title": "Click on big button"}'}, {'referer': 'http://example.com/fgd', 'type': 'PAGE', 'page': '{"title": "Page title second"}'}]);
```

I want to select count of hits with type = 'PAGE'.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List is not the right structure for you use-case, consider the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE statistics(
  client_id VARCHAR,
  hit_type text,
  referer text,
  page text,
  event text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((client_id,hit_type), referer)
);

// Insert hits
INSERT INTO statistics(client_id, hit_type, referer, page)
VALUES('client1','PAGE', 'http://example.com/asd', '{"title": "Page title"}'); 

INSERT INTO statistics(client_id, hit_type, referer, event)
VALUES('client1','EVENT', 'http://example.com/dsa', '{"title": "Click on big button"}'); 

INSERT INTO statistics(client_id, hit_type, referer, page)
VALUES('client1','PAGE', 'http://example.com/fgd', '{"title": "Page title second"}');

//Select all hits for a given client and hit type:
SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE client_id='xxx' AND hit_type='PAGE';
```

Please note that with the above schema, **it is not recommended** to have more than 100 millions of referers for each couple (client_id,hit_type)